# Pandas: convert all values of a column to datetime when the column values are mix of string and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column which contains values like this

```
         04-04-2007
         14-03-2008
         14-03-2008
2011-10-10 00:00:00
2011-10-10 00:00:00
         27-04-2012
         27-04-2012
         28-03-2014
2014-03-28 00:00:00
2017-03-31 00:00:00
2017-03-31 00:00:00
2018-04-02 00:00:00
```

As can be seen, few values are datetime and few are string. I want all to be converted to datetime.

`pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')` throws an error when it encounters datetime type values

Comment: Try it with `pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='ignore')` to leave values which are already correctly formatted unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does errors='ignore' help? This should skip the values it can't parse and return the original input (so, in theory, returning the datetime value)

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='ignore')
```